# How to get nested JSON Reply with WCF an Entity Framework

Tags: json, entity-framework

I have 2 models, A Order Header and Order Detail.

I want to end up with a JSON reply from the Server that looks like:

```
--OrderHeader 1
  |
   --OrderDetails 1
--OrderHeader 2
  |
   --Order Detail 2
```

Would I use entity framework create some sort of sub query wand return this via my WebGet, or would I run separate queries and integrate the format after the results have been obtained?

Here are my Viewmodels:

```
 public class OpenOrderHeader
{
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public int OrderID { get; set; }
    public int OrderUniqueNumber { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfProductsOnOrder { get; set; }
    public DateTime OrderDateCreated { get; set; }
    public DateTime OrderDateUpdated { get; set; }
    public string OrderLocalOnline { get; set; }
    public int BranchID { get; set; }
    public string PaymentMethod { get; set; }
    public int OrderStatus { get; set; }
    public string OrderCurrency { get; set; }
    public decimal OrderConversionRate { get; set; }
    public decimal SubTotalInclTax { get; set; }
    public decimal SubTotalExclTax { get; set; }
    public decimal DiscountInclTax { get; set; }
    public decimal DiscountExclTax { get; set; }
    public decimal ShippingInclTax { get; set; }
    public decimal ShippingExclTax { get; set; }
    public decimal PaymentFeeInclTax { get; set; }
    public decimal PaymentFeeExclTax { get; set; }

}

public class OpenOrderProducts
{
    public int OrderID { get; set; }
    public string ProductSKUName { get; set; }
    public int ProductSKUID { get; set; }
    public string ProductSKUStockCode { get; set; }
    public DateTime ProductAddedToOrder { get; set; }
    public int QtyOfProductsOnOrder { get; set; }
    public decimal UnitPriceinclTax { get; set; }
    public decimal UnitPriceExclTax { get; set; }
    public decimal UnitDiscountInclTax { get; set; }
    public decimal UnitDiscountExclTax { get; set; }
    public decimal LineItemTotalIncludingTax { get; set; }
    public decimal LineItemExclTax { get; set; }
    public decimal LineItemShippingCost { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14849876/861716

Comment: @GertArnold So essentially i must just create lazy loading instance based on the foreignkey constraint. So my Class might look like:

  `public class CustomerOrder
    {
        public int CustomerID { get; set; }
        public int OrderID { get; set; }
        public int OrderUniqueNumber { get; set; }
        public int NumberOfProductsOnOrder { get; set; }
        //Rest of orderHeader
        public virtual ICollection<CustomerOrderProduct> OrderProducts { get; set; }
    }`

Comment: In your case you could query all data in one shot, using `Include`. The related link is about a recursive structure, which requires more than one query.

Comment: @GertArnold Thanks. Just post as answer, will mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a navigation property `Orderdetails` on the `OrderHeader` entity. Then you can query

```
var data = db.OrderHeaders.Include(h => h.Orderdetails).ToList();
```

and serialize data into JSON.

I think that in the classes you show `OpenOrderHeader` would have a collection of `OpenOrderProducts`?

```
public virtual ICollection<OpenOrderProduct> OpenOrderProducts { get; set; }
```

(As you see, I would change the name of the class in `OpenOrderProduct`, no plural)